# difference in time between two date

Tags: java

I have to find the difference in time between two different date
i try this:

```
Date d1 = null;
Date d2 = null;
d1 = format.parse(startDate);
d2 = format.parse(endDate);

long diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();

diffSeconds = diff / 1000 % 60;          
diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000) % 60;         
diffHours = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000);
```

but when i set `startDate` to 15/05/2017 23:40:10 and`endDate` to 16/05/2017 00:05:55

the output is:

```
diffSeconds = -15;
diffMinutes = -25;
diffHours   = -23;
```

how i can fix this? thank you.

Comment: How is `format` defined  ?

Comment: SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yy/MM/yyyy - HH:mm:ss");

Comment: it work for every date and hour but when i have 23:... and 00:.... the output is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Either you made a mistake in the date format, or you've switched the start and end dates.

The following works perfectly fine:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

String startDate = "15/05/2017 23:40:10";
String endDate = "16/05/2017 00:05:55";

Date d1 = format.parse(startDate);
Date d2 = format.parse(endDate);

long diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();
long diffSeconds = diff / 1000 % 60;
long diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000) % 60;
long diffHours = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000);

System.out.println(diffHours + " " + diffMinutes + " " + diffSeconds);
```

Output is:

```
0 25 45
```